# Point a domain (example.com) to subdomain (example.xyz.com) with Route53

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, route53

I'm looking to point my root-level domain; `example.com` to a subdomain `sub.xyz.example`. The goal is that users visiting `example.com` should have all content loaded from `sub.xyz.example`; without any references to the latter.

I've tried the following -

```
CNAME:
*.example.com -> (value) sub.xyz.example
```

note: Route53 won't let me create a record-keeping the "*" part blank. That is `example.com` is not allowed to point to `sub.xyz.example`. I also tried replacing it with `@.example.com`, but it doesn't seem to work.

OR do I need to wait a little more time?

What works -
I can successfully get the site to load by simply creating an "A" record and using the IP.

However, I'm hesitant to share IP addresses with folks who want to map their sites to my service.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: In other words, do you want DNS queries for `[pattern].example.com` to resolve to `[pattern].sub.xyz.example`, for every value of `[pattern]`?

Comment: For public zones (domain names), DNS servers are public. Therefore, you cannot hide the IP address.

Comment: When you say "However, I'm hesitant to share IP address with folks who want to map their sites to my service," what exactly do you mean by that? Do you mean that you are trying to set up a service that lets people map their sites to your service, but are hesitant to share IPs because you'd rather have a CNAME setup in case the IPs change? Or do you mean that you are trying to run a private service, you are trying to prevent grifters from mapping their sites to your service, and to that end you want to keep IPs hidden altogether?

Comment: I want to let anyone point their domain `abc.com` or `pqr.com` to a subdomain on my service (example.com) - like `abc.example.com` or `pqr.example.com` by changing CNAME record for `abc.com` or `pqr.com`. This is because IPs may change over time. I'm not hiding the IPs. I couldn't find a way to do this with Route53. The goal is to have wordpress.com like service where people can point their domains to subdomains and have a complete whitelisted site running.

Comment: Ive not tried this (I run my own nameservers)  but I wonder if you could use the "alias" pseudo record type - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Comment: @davidgo - alias doesn't let me define what I want. I'm guessing the issue is mostly related to CNAME record defining.

Comment: You cant do what you are asking with cnames & route53 or not.  It breaches the spec.